# Meteor Collection Update Async?

Tags: meteor

I'm having trouble understanding and implementing the following.  I want a div with a fixed height to list all values from an array.  The css overflow is set to scroll.  When I push a new item to the array, I would like the div to scroll to the bottom.  In this case it's a fixed string "hello".

```
$('#click').scrollTop($('#click')[0].scrollHeight)
```

It works under some conditions (if I use jQuery to append to the div), but it doesn't work when I'm updating the database.  It seems it scrolls to the bottom and then the new value is added to array.  Which causes it to have the new items hidden on the bottom and I need to manually scroll to the bottom to see the new items.

I tried putting the jQuery scroll, as a callback.  I'm a beginner when it comes to understanding async, and if I had to guess, the scroll jQuery is being completed before the Collection update.

```
List = new Meteor.Collection('list');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.div1.helpers({
        list:function() {
            return List.find({_id: '001'}).fetch()[0].names
        }
    }),
    Template.div1.events({
        'click #click':function() {
            List.update({_id: '001'}, {$push: {names: 'Hello'}});
            $('.div1').scrollTop($('.div1')[0].scrollHeight)
        }  
    })
}
```

The HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>updateTest</title>
</head>    

<body>
    {{> div1}}
</body>  

<Template name='div1'>
    <div class='div1'>
        {{#each list}}
            {{this}} <br />
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <input type='button' id='click' value='click'/>
</Template>
```

EDIT: fix targeting the incorrect jQuery object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the callback from the `.update` method, which is what you're asking (async update)

```
List.update({_id: '001'}, {$push: {names: 'Hello'}}, function(err) {
    $('#click').scrollTop($('#click')[0].scrollHeight)
});
```

or use a `Tracker.afterFlush`

```
List.update({_id: '001'}, {$push: {names: 'Hello'}});

Tracker.afterFlush(function() {   

    $('#click').scrollTop($('#click')[0].scrollHeight)

});
```

The reason I suggest using `Tracker.afterFlush` is this makes sure that the scroll is fired after any reactive changes have affected the DOM, this is more to the intention of what you want to do as opposed to using the callback from the update.

Both should work either way, except the callback-async way waits for a response from the server & this can take a bit more time if its far away or offline at the time - the DOM will most likely be drawn by then.

Comment: Using the update callback, I tried this before, my syntax was wrong when I tried it, this works.  I've never worked with the second solution.  Just read the docs, this runs after all the .update is complete?  I just want to clarify the problem was while the update was in progress, my jQuery already scrolled to the bottom?

Comment: @captainKevin the problem was caused by JQuery scrolling to the bottom before the DOM was updated. All that was needed to be done is to make sure you scrolled after it was updated

Comment: This is because of Asynchronous programming?  Is this always the case when accessing the database?  Is there a rule of thumb when I need to be aware of things completing before I intended.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just targeting the wrong element. In fact, this itself should work:

```
  Template.div1.events({
    'click #click':function() {
      List.update({_id: '001'}, {$push: {names: 'Hello'}});
      $('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight)
    }  
  })
```

By the way, your query on `list` helper can be simplified to a `findOne` since the `_id` field is uniquely indexed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry that was my fault.  It should have targeted the the div class $(.div1).  Not sure of the procedure, should I edit my original post?  Thanks for the tip on findOne, I'm new to Mongo and Meteor.

Comment: No problem. By the way: the reason this works is that Meteor has something called latency compensation, where the local collection updates instantly (which is reflected on the DOM just as quickly). So you don't necessarily have to wait for the update call to the server to scroll to the element in the DOM (though, Akshat's suggestions are the recommended way of ensuring your app works as expected. For example, if the update fails on the server, the DOM element will be promptly removed).